# how can I print ADB devices list?

Tags: python, android, adb

I'm a total beginner and I struggle to acces to the ADB devices list and print it.

here is my starting code:

```
import ppadb

from ppadb.client import Client

adb = Client(host='localhost', port=5037)
devices = adb.devices()
```

This code succeed to find all the ABD devices connect to my computer. Unfortunately, when i type this

```
print (devices)
```

the console return

```
[<ppadb.device.Device object at 0x00000139C6FC8F40>]
```

How can I manage to have acces to a usable list ?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to loop through the `Device` objects and return the serial

```
for device in devices:
    print (device.serial)
```

this roughly corresponds to the outcome of `adb devices`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seeing each print give me a host with a unique port, I can continue from there :)